# Kubernetes NodePort - Ufw/Iptables ignored?

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kubernetes-ingress, ufw

I opened a Kubernetes NodePort on a machine and blocked all traffic to this port with the following rule:

```
sudo ufw deny 30001
```

But I can still access that port via browser. Is it common? I can't find any information on that in the docs.

Comment: deny in what direction? ingress , or egress?

Comment: try `ufw deny proto tcp to any port 30001`

Comment: also make sure you are running that deny command on the node which u are accessing from browser

Comment: its ingress. I tried your command above but no changes either. Also I checked to deny on the correct host, no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the issue: `kube-proxy` is writing `iptables` rules (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-kube-proxy-writing-iptables-rules) which are catched before the `ufw` rules one added manually. This can be confirmed by checking the order in the output of `iptables -S -v`.

Comment: I believe that the nodeport is available but since the service acceses the pods through iptable rules you shouldn't be able to reach the pods themselves